# C# socket сервер, как построить архитектуру

Tags: c#, websocket

Разрабатываю сокет серверное приложение для игры. Интересует, как правильно разработать архитектуру приложения. Планирую использоваться websockets-csharp. Также посмотрел другие, суть их заключается в том, что они уведомляют мое приложении о 3-х видах событий (коннект, дисконнет и новое сообщение)

Вопросы:

1. Как реализовать схему (pipeline) парсера и взаимодействия с сообщениями. (планируется порядка 20-30 типов сообщений)
2. Как реализовать классы, чтобы это было во-первых удобно использовать, во-вторых грамотно с точки зрения архитектуры приложения.

Может быть вы подскажете работающие примеры с сокетами, просто так они не находятся.

Comment: надо с нуля разработать или можете использовать готовое решение?

Comment: А что есть готовое решение? В качестве сокетной библиотеки буду использовать https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp.

Answer (score 4):

Если для игры требуется организовать обмен сообщениями/данными в реальном времени, и в своем проекты вы можете использовать готовые решения, то есть следующие решения с открытым кодом от Microsoft:

- [ASP.NET SignalR](http://signalr.net/) (на [github](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)) -- позволяет в real-time обмениваться сообщениями в web.
  Использует WebSockets в качестве транспорта, если это возможно, или другие технологии, включая long pooling.
- Microsoft [Orleans](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/) -- фреймворк для создания распределенных масштабируемых систем на основе .NET
  Используется для создания Halo 4 gaming cloud engine. Подробнее - [тут](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/orleans/).

---

UPDATE:

Пример WebSocketServer на основе OWIN, Katana - [тут](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/Katana/WebSocketSample/WebSocketServer/Startup.cs).

OWIN -- это Open Web Interface for .NET (не зависит от ASP.NET).
Katana — это OWIN-совместимый хост написанный Microsoft.

Пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487125).

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. Нужен именно постоянно работающий сервер. Signal R это больше к сайтам. Мне для игры нужно еще обрабатывать серверную логику, рассылать пуши и пр.

Comment: SignalR позволяет рассылать уведомления подключенным клиентам. и использует WebSockets .

Comment: Это я понимаю. Проблема же в том, что мне нужно нечно вроде службы. Чтобы по некоторым событиям (по расписанию, по событиям, еще по каким-то данным) отправлять сообщения. + SignalR не очень хорошо работает в iOS. Вопрос же больше об архитектуре построения серверного приложения с сокетами.

Comment: _"мне нужно нечно вроде службы."_ -- на сервере у вас .net? если да, то добавляете сборку SignalR. а на клиентах используется javascript, который входит в пакет SignalR. дальше пишете логику работы серверной части и клиентской. а передачей сообщений/данных через WebSokets будет заниматься SignalR

Comment: На сервере .net, я не хочу костылить в виде javascript и webview. Читал, что это не совсем корректно работает.

Comment: _"я не хочу костылить в виде javascript и webview."_ -- никакого webview не нужно. в SignalR входит обычный javascript-файл, такой же как, например, jquery.js. Если у вас клиенты не web-страницы, то javascript использовать не надо.

Comment: а минус за что? за Microsoft? :)

Comment: Промахнулся, но вообще это ответ не на мой вопрос))) Вопрос как сделать обработчик, а не что выбрать) Попробовал вчера SignalR. Это все-таки не то.

Comment: @Dmitriy _"SignalR. Это все-таки не то"_ -- вроде в нем есть то что нужно: "коннект, дисконнет и новое сообщение". или что-то еще надо?

Comment: Вопрос не о том, что использовать. А о том, как построить обработчик сообщений, парсер (роутер) и архитектуру приложения. Независимо от используемой технологии.

Comment: @Dmitriy наверное лучше всего смотреть исходник существующих проектов. в ответе есть ссылки на открытый код на github

Comment: @Dmitriy _"независимо"_ -- совсем независимо не получится. но asp.net 5 может работать на windows, linux, osx.

Comment: Мне нужно сейчас и без ASP.NET =) Чтобы его на сокетах совсем не было. Это получится)

Comment: @Dmitriy на сервере должно быть что-то, что обрабатывает запросы. можно использовать OWIN, он не привязан к старому ASP.NET. добавил update в ответ.

Comment: @Dmitriy, SignalR это то, что Вам нужно. Вы можете сделать консольное приложение, к нему подключить библиотеку SignalR и реализовать обработку запросов, рассылку пуш-уведомлений и весь функционал, что Вас интересует. Но можете потерять кучу времени и реализовать всё сами на основе обычных WebSocket, HttpListner и прочего.

Comment: @Umed у вас есть примеры приложений на SignalR, в которых реализовано что-то посложнее чата? Буду благодарен. Но в таком случае нет нативных клиентов для iOS (Swift)

Comment: @Stack, Что такое OWIN и Katana я знаю. Они мне нравятся в большом ASP.NET и использую их везде (мое творение https://bitbucket.org/oxozle/utilities/src/c029063b0232e743b2f7022ab4a981cb27995d23/Oxozle.IdentityFramework.Models/?at=master), но вот как подружить SignalR + Swift (iOS sockets) не придумать. И есть ли примеры, где логика сокетов посложнее чата? Буду благодарен.

Comment: @Dmitriy через SignalR можно сделать совместный графический редактор, а не только чат. и наверное надо отдельный вопрос создать и указать теги Swift и SignalR

Comment: @Dmitriy, готовых примеров нет, но в качестве библиотеки для iOS, я думаю, можно взять это https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR